# OpenMPI mpirun hangs after giving `failed-daemon-launch` error

Tags: mpi, openmpi

When several nodes are down and can’t be connected via ssh, mpirun gives the following error and hangs forever. The expected behavior in this case should be terminating with an error code, however it’s hanging.

---

ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
This usually is caused by:

- not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default
- lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.
- the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.
- compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.
- an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).
  ———————————————————————————————————————————————

Is mpirun doing anything in the background? Is there any configuration I can add to make mpirun exit in this case?

Comment: which version of Open MPI are you running? what happens when you manually `ssh`? does it fail or hang?

Comment: Also, how many nodes in your machinefile ?

Comment: I'm running openmpi 2.1.1. This happens no matter how many nodes I have (4, 16, 32). I have been able to reproduce this by just turning one of my node down.

Comment: I am afraid this is quite an old version of Open MPI that is no more supported. I do invite you to try the latest Open MPI 4.0.2